# When posting an image on Facebook, can I control what part of the image is shown in the preview?

Tags: facebook, images

I want to post an image in a Facebook Group where only a small part of the image will be in the preview and have the rest of the image be visible only when you click on it. I would like to choose exactly what part of the image will be viewable pre-click. I can't find a good way to do it.